# How can I save listbox items into a string

Tags: vb.net, string, visual-studio-2012, listboxitems

I want to save all the items I have in my listbox into a string in this kind of format.

String = listboxitem1,listboxitem2,listboxitem3,listboxitem4,listboxitem5....

So then later once I want to pull them back up I can use a breaker and break it up, then load them into listbox1 again. I have a rough idea how to do this but not sure. I was thinking save 1 item in listbox1 at a time then separate them with "," then put it in the string. I have no idea how to put that in code though.

SOLUTION!

Found that the solution was I load it into a listbox, then I added this code

```
For Each Item As Object In ListBox1.Items
                [StringNameHere!] &= (Item & ",")
Next
```

Then I load the string by splitting the string between every ","

Comment: Was you problem resolved? If so, please post resolution as an answer and mark it as accepted. This way you will let other members know no further attention to this question is needed. Thank you.

Comment: it was, I can't answer my own question untill tomorrow so I put it with the question.

Comment: How come you cannot answer your own question? Is there a new rule on StackOverflow? You cannot accept your answer for 2 days, but you should be able to post it any time, even at the same time with posting a question (share knowledge - Q/A style).

Comment: This is what I get for trying 

"Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 7/7/2014 4:34:30 AM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Comment: Interesting, never heard of this limitation. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: You can go ahead and C+P my answer to make it solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you have solved your own question. Just an additional suggestion for you if it is not a must for you to store your data as string. What if the value in your ListBox contains a "," ? It will give you another row since you are spliting it with a "," in the later part.

Try using the below:

To Store the value from ListBox:

```
 Dim itemListToStore As New List(Of ListItem)
 For Each item As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
     itemListToStore.Add(item)
 Next
```

To populate the ListBox with stored value:

```
 For Each pullOutItem As ListItem In itemListToStore
     ListBox1.Items.Add(pullOutItem.Text)
 Next
```

This will overcome the problem of delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click    
dim itm_count as integer
dim s as string
s=""
itm_count= list1.items.count
For k As Integer = 0 To list1.Items.Count
  s = list1.Items(k).ToString & ","
Next
MsgBox(s) 'it will shows the item separated by comas in message box
end sub
```